# Anchor link fires only after swiping left or right in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I got a carousel which each slide got an image and some copy. Each slide is all clickable and the anchor tag surrounds both image and copy(absolute positioned on top of all).
In desktop mode everything works well. 
But, in mobile mode, the anchor tag fires only after swiping the carousel left or right (touch event).
The anchor tag should just take you to the landing page specified but it works only after swiping. Very weird.
Also If I press on the 'li' a little longer then the anchor will work.

Does anyone can help?
Thanks!

Here is the markup:

```
 <li>
         <div class="promo-image">             
                <img src="some source">           
         </div>

         <div class="promo-wrapper ">
           <div class="promo-block">
             <h3 class="title">blah</h3>
                <div class="module-copy">
                     <h6>more blah</h6>
                </div>
                <a class="cta" target="" title="blah" href="/relative-landing-Url">Explore</a>
           </div>
         </div>

         <a target="" title="Explore" href="relative-landing-url" class="carousel-wrap-link"></a>  

</li>
```

Comment: Which js library are you using?

Comment: JQuery and Vanilla JS. I've also noticed that If I press longer and keep clicking on it, then it works as well.

Comment: It's really difficult to help you without seeing the carousel js code. That was my reasoning for asking about the library. Remember to use "stack snippets".

Comment: But there's no JS involved in the anchor click. It's a simple href. It's not driven by any JS.

Comment: I know the anchor click is not driven by JS, but your carousel is. The carousel JS is likely to be interfering with the link. --- leaving out your JS will hinder any help you might get.

Comment: I understand that. 
The main problem is that If I keep my thumb pressed a little longer then the achor url link gets fired. Otherwise it's not being picked up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125523/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-beppe).